# how to clear all previous text from text area?

Tags: vb.net, textarea

i tried this code,but it is throwing error.

```
Private Sub ClearText
    Dim ctl As Control

    ' Clear all the TextBoxes on the form.
    For Each ctl In Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextArea Then ctl.Text = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest some logic, thanks

Comment: I presume that class `Control` does not have any property called `Text`. You'd have to cast `ctl` to `TextArea` to access it's `Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to cast ctl to type TextArea before you can set property Text

I think this will work

```
Private Sub ClearText
    Dim ctl As Control

    ' Clear all the TextBoxes on the form.
    For Each ctl In Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextArea Then CType(ctl, TextArea).Text = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

You can also use DirectCast, it might provide somewhat better performance than CType.